# Example of a function that is not continuous but Riemann Integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I have recently stumbled upon the following function  $f [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:

$$ 
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
e,  & \text{if } x = 0 \\
\sum_{n=0}^y \frac{1}{n!}, & \text{if } x>0 
\end{cases}
$$
where $y = [\frac{1}{x}]$ is the integer part of $\frac{1}{x}$.
The claim is that it is Riemann integrable but has infinitely many discontinuities. I clearly can see that it is Riemann Integrable since it is a decreasing function on the given interval $[0,1]$. However, I am not sure about the proof of being infinitely discontinuous. Here is the proof that came with this example:

Take $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and set $x_0 = \frac{1}{n}$. Then, $\lim_{x\to x_0^-} f(x) - \lim_{x\to x_0^+} f(x) = \frac{1}{n!}$

Here I understand that discontinuity follows, however, I am not sure how they obtained that the difference is $\frac{1}{n!}$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Starfall I might have explained it not very well but what I mean here is that it is a monotonic function, i.e. strictly decreasing and so Riemann Integrable.

Comment: @IVU: Neat example!

Comment: that should be $f(x).$

Comment: @zhw. Indeed, it should be, thank you

Answer (score 2):

We are seeing the **step discontinuity.**

Let $x_{0}=\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{3}$. As we approach from the **left,** 
$$\color{blue}{2.9,\ 2.99,\ 2.999},\dots$$
The function value is 
$$\frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!}$$
As we approach from the **right,**
$$\color{red}{ 3.1,\ 3.01,\ 3.001}$$
The function value is
$$\frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \boxed{\frac{1}{3!}}$$

The **difference** is $\frac{1}{n!} = \frac{1}{3!}$

[image: factstep]

Comment: Oh, this makes sense now, thank you!

Comment: You need to take $x_0 = 1/3$ and take the inverses of the other numbers as well. Other than this, +1.

Comment: @Michał Miśkiewicz: You careful reading and comment helps me and many other users. Thanks.